# Recommend a Linux or browser-based Venn diagram drawing tool

Tags: php, flash, charts, venn-diagram

I'm looking for a tool to draw good-looking [Venn diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram), for use on a Linux-based PHP site, which already employs Flash for graph drawing ([Open Flash Chart 2](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/)).  Free (as in beer or speech) would be nice, but isn't essential.

So it should be one of the following (in my rough order of preference):

- Browser based (Flash)
- PHP library
- Linux command line app
- Web service

So far the options I'm aware of are:

- [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/types.html#venn)
- Write something myself using [PHP GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or Flash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Google chart api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/types.html#venn).

Answer (score 4):

Use [Venny](http://bioinfogp.cnb.csic.es/tools/venny/index.html)

Very easy to use and goes up to four groups.

Answer (score -1):

Write something yourself using [PHP GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or Flash.